# Passing a parameter between python classes

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write my first python module. The module is a wrapper for an api.

I'd like to allow users to set an api key in one of two ways: using a static configuration file or dynamically when they initiate the class.

How do I pass the key from `__init__.py` to `functions.py` if the key is in fact set dynamically?

File structure:

```
package/
   __init__.py
   config.py
   functions.py
```

File contents:

**__init__.py**

```
import config 

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key if key else config.key
        ...
```

**functions.py**

```
import config 

class MyFunctions(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = ?
        self.base_url = config.base

    def function1(self, my_id):
        endpoint = urlencode({'id':my_id, 'key':self.key})
        ...
```

**config.py**

```
key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
base= 'http://xxxxx.com/api'
```

Comment: Why not just make it a kwarg: `def __init__(self, key=config.key):`

Comment: How does functions.py become aware of the key if it is set in __init__.py

Comment: whoever is using functions.py will supply the key when they instantiate the `MyFunctions` instance.

Comment: @chad doesn't that need to take place in MyClass and not MyFunctions? Say I have multiple classes needing the key?

Comment: Any class that needs the key should get it as a parameter. If you need to dry up instantiation of a bunch of objects using a given key, you can make a factory method/class in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to set the same key for all the classes in the `functions` module, do so in the initialization of the package, overwriting the variables set by default in the `config` module.

Then import the `config` module and use the variables

**config.py**

```
key = 1
base_url = 'www.xyz.com/'
```

**__init__.py**

```
import config
import functions

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, key=config.key):
        config.key = key
```

**functions.py**

```
import config 

class MyFunctionsA(object):
    def function1(self, my_id):
        print(config.base_url)
        print(config.key)

class MyFunctionsB(object):
    def function1(self, my_id):
        print(config.base_url)
        print(config.key)

class MyFunctionsC(object):
    def function1(self, my_id):
        print(config.base_url)
        print(config.key)
```

So you can use them as

```
>>> import package as pk
>>> pk.MyClass(9)
<package.MyClass object at 0x7f2133e96d10>
>>> f1 = pk.functions.MyFunctionsA()
>>> f2 = pk.functions.MyFunctionsB()
>>> f3 = pk.functions.MyFunctionsC()
>>> f1.function1(100)
www.xyz.com/
9
>>> f2.function1(100)
www.xyz.com/
9
>>> f3.function1(100)
www.xyz.com/
9
```

However, in case the key is an instance attribute of `MyFunctions`, let the users pass the key to its `__init__`, as usual.

Note: I ignore why you need to instantiate `MyClass` to set things up. It may be simpler to use a plain function instead.

Comment: This solves the problem. Out of curiosity, though, if  I have a lot of classes that need the key, is there a better way to pass the key to all classes?

Comment: hello, please see my revised answer. I have scrapped the previous solution altogether. Now it's done properly.